# UTF-8 error with Cucumber feature

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cucumber, meta-search

I’m using Rails 3.0.7 and ruby 1.9.2 with cucumber and capybara. I just had this problem, and I can’t find a solution :(

> invalid byte sequence in US-ASCII (ArgumentError)
>         :10:in `synchronize'
>         (eval):2:in`click_button'
>         ./features/step_definitions/vouchers_company_steps.rb:25:in `/^I use it in my voucher UI$/'

I think it has something to do with the form submission which is a GET and the famous utf8 tick. I don’t have this problem with my other forms. This one is using metasearch, I don’t know if it can help.

Comment: Are you sure your step definition file doesn't contain an UTF-8 character anywhere?

Answer (score 1):

add to the top of the file

```
# encoding: utf-8
```

Answer (score 1):

encoding: utf-8 didn’t help.

I narrowed down the problem and found it occurs only within cucumber/capybara when submitting a form with a GET request. The error appears with the utf8=✓ parameter…

*EDIT*: Found the culprit: I’m using escape_utils and removing it make capybara work again.